# database logic for tracking each and every operation in my web application

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am developing an Web application. In my application, I need to keep track of each and every operation for every logged in user.

I have planned following for achieving this task:-

- I will create stored procedure in mysql.
- I will trigger this procedure on each table's insert , update
  delete.

This is an tough job for me. Will anybody direct me in the right way?

I am using **PHP** based **Codeigniter** framework and **mysql** database.

**Please help me**

**Edit:-** Considering above steps , I'm not able to develop. Now I'm in puzzled condition. So are there anybody who can give me the idea?

**what I need is - after login of a user , track each and every thing that done by that user.**

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in control of the MySQL database then enabling the MySQL's query log would be the easiest solution. In my.cnf (e.q. on Debian `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) find in the section `[mysql]` and adjust the settings to look like this:

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
```

Then restart MySQL using (again, Debian example) `sudo service mysql restart`.

If you are dealing with a MySQL < 5.1 the settings would look like this:

```
log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

If you need to read the log data from your application, you could dump the log into a database table instead of a file. To achieve this add the following line to your `my.cnf` in section `[mysqld]`:

```
log_output = TABLE
```

You can then read the query log with

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log;
```

Comment: how will I access that file in my application? and how will I show the message which log file containing

Comment: You can simply dump the log into a table. Added details above.

Comment: where mysql log file generally save?

Comment: and if I follow Your logic - then only 1 application can be executed from 1 server. Not more than one. So not suitable and not generic.

Comment: In the example above the path is defined in the my.cnf with 

    log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log

Comment: ok. check my above comment. Do You have any generic solution?

Comment: If you have multiple applications running on this DB then this approach is not going to work. In this case you have to look for a solution on application level. However, I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter and its DB layer. 

A decorator or subclass for the PDO class could do the trick. "Simply" wrap the execute() and query() classes and log the SQL. But again, there might be a better solution in CodeIgniter's toolset.

Comment: Btw.: I'd refrain from Stored Procedures in shared environments, especially if the requirements for the target system are not well defined. That's because SP require special privileges which are often not GRANT'ed by shared hosters.

Comment: ok. thanks for Your advice. Though I'm not able to accept this answer but I'll give You upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google analytics, you can use google analytics to keept track of all operation done by your logged in users. Do look over google analytics custom variables and event tracking. Check here [Custom Variable](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) and [Event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)

Comment: no , it's not like that. Actually it will notified all time like FB notification.

Comment: Look for graph db like neo4j, it will help you. Check www.sportskeeda.com notification system